# Complicated password in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, password

I wrote a script to call API, code like below:

```
#!/bin/bash    
curl -s "https://openapi.domain.com/api/rest/login?user=khoitran&pass=gkoq@Ggk!5648@#&output=json"
```

the script did not work so I tried to run it outside the script to find out what wrong. Turns out my complicated pass is the cause

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ curl -s "https://openapi.domain.com/api/rest/login?user=khoitran&pass=gkoq@Ggk!5648@#&output=json"
-bash: !5648: event not found
```

(my pass is: gkoq@Ggk!5648@#)

I have tried several ways to deal with that password (of course, except change it, lol) but nothing works.
Could you please advise.

Comment: In bash the `!` is a command that references the bash history so it tries to fill in the 5648. entry in your bash history... as already mentioned in the answers you can avoid this by putting your strings in single quotes `'` so variables won't be evaluated (and I hope you didn't post a real password here ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out a way to do it, use a method called urlencode to parse the pass into "gkoq%40Ggk%215648%40%23" then put it directly to my scripts.
To parse the pass use this link
https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urlencode/

Answer (score 3):

The `!` is not getting translated as a `!`, it is actually running it as a command.  So, encase your password in single quotes `'`:

```
'gkoq@Ggk!5648@#'
```

You can test it with an echo line to make sure it is working correctly:

```
:~$ echo 'gkoq@Ggk!5648@#'
gkoq@Ggk!5648@#
```

Now, set the `pass` variable to it:

```
:~$ pass='gkoq@Ggk!5648@#'
:~$ echo $pass
gkoq@Ggk!5648@#
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But somehow your method not work in my case. I don't know why, echo returned correct password but when apply to the curl command, it returned 'user login information error', i'm sure user/pass I put in also correct.
One more thing your method cannot apply to script, cause I already tried it before (use variable, then put pass=$variable into curl command) and failed.

Comment: @Khoi.T Unfortunately without being able to run your command itself, we can only guess.  One other thing before I recommend that you change your password to something that doesn't have a ! in it, try escaping the !.  Put a \ right before the !.  Remove the single quotes and try it as gkoq@Ggk\!5648@#

Comment: hi Terrance,
I finally found out a way to do it, use a method called urlencode to parse the pass into "gkoq%40Ggk%215648%40%23"
anyway, thank you for your helping

Comment: @Khoi.T Totally spaced that one off.  Makes sense since URLs convert special characters to other meanings.  Glad you found that one to work for you.  :)

Comment: @Khoi.T You might want to write that as your answer.  You also might want to include any references where you might have found that information.  I think that is really good to know, and others might stumble across the same issue.  You also can accept your own answers.